# Why are the UITableViewCells in Debug View Hierarchy staggered?

Tags: ios, uitableview, xcode6

I have an array that is the datasource for my UITableViewController. When an item is added to the array I use `self.tableView.reloadData()` on the main thread to show the new item in the TableView. When I inspect the table view in Debug View Hierarchy in Xcode I see that the UITableViewCells are staggered outward.  Is this normal or is it a bug that I have to correct? In the Debug Navigator, the cells all have the same parent.

[image]

[image]

Comment: The hierarchy shown in the Debug Navigator is correct. Not sure about the other screenshot though, I don't have Xcode 6.

Comment: A little late, but the debug view hierarchy is also correct. Every single view is shown on its own plane as that is how it will be drawn. When you have multiple subviews, they still have an order from top to bottom.